# Resolving Prism Services in MVVM

Tags: c#, mvvm, prism, unity-container

Trying to Resolve my stored services objects (Mostly as Singleton interfaces) in the Container,

There is a **Domain Module** which it's **ViewModels** will use the **Services** of Services Module.

Where and how do you recommend for this, Resolving inside the Domain **Module** or inside the **ViewModels** of the Domain Module ?

If I could do this inside ViewModel's Constructor, Is the below code enough, after the service is registered, What if I don't want to do this :

```
    public DetailsViewModel(IWService wSvc,)
    {
        wService = wSvc;
    }
```

What is the best approach getting the Services objects (stored in Container) in the "View Models" ?

*What I provided here just is as a sample.
thanks for any help*

Comment: As long as your view model (DetailsViewModel) is being resolved by the unity container, the code you have above should give you services in the view model. What you have got is the standard way I have seen Prism applications created. If your view model is not being created by the container, you will need to pass the services into the view model's constructor yourself. I've just been writing an application using Prism, and I have largely abandoned MVVM in favor of a more MVP like approach as I find the whole concept of a VM (View Model) very confusing without a presenter or controller class.

Comment: @Jay thanks for the info, sorry I wasn't at the PC at that time, I'm still dealing with it and trying to understand and make use of some darker parts, I like it somehow and my code lacks some pieces which I'm trying to fix them. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend that your ViewModels obtain the services that they use through Dependency Injection of the Constructor. Whatever approach you decide on, you should keep in mind that one of the main concepts is the ability to test your ViewModels. Usually, this would involve being able to supply your ViewModels with mock implementations of your services to test their behavior independently of those services. If you use constructor injection, you can simple create your mock services and then pass them into the constructor of your ViewModel for testing if you were to write unit tests. Even if you do not plan on writing unit tests at this time, I think it is a valid reason to get into the habit of following a certain design scheme.

```
public class SomeViewModel
{
    private IEventAggregator events;
    private ISomeService someService;

    public SomeViewModel(IEventAggregator events, ISomeService someService)
    {
        this.events = events;
        this.someService = someService;
    }
}
```

Comment: I came into the same point as you provided, but a simple thing to ask: Instead of getting the services I tried to get the IUnityContainer via the constructor and right after that called a later defined method of FetchServices which I defined my Services there, Is it OK ? or Is it recommended in such a situation to make the Container singleton or not ?

Comment: @LastBye No, what you just described is not a good idea. You are basically making a singleton or service-location style pattern which somewhat negates the purpose of dependency injection in the first place. You may want to look up "Composition Root", while I do not agree with it completely, it explains why you do not want to do what you just mentioned

Comment: @LastBye In short, try to limit your Container's Usage to each Module's entry-point. I would inject IUnityContainer into your IModule's (implementation) Constructor. Then, register your types and resolve its components in the Initialize method, at least for Unity. Usually other types you resolve or that get injected into other types should be able to get their dependencies injected into the constructor.

Comment: +1s, Got what you said, What about separating FetchServices from the constructor (but not the singleton Container, and also it would be called from the constructor) ? This could be some help on faster class generating and classifying. (The first part of my idea)

Comment: What do you mean by separating it from the constructor? What do you mean by faster generating and classifying? I would avoid using ServiceLocator directly or the container directly in your view model. I would also avoid property injection using DependencyAttribute ( [Dependency] ) because a constructor shows that a class has a clear dependency when creating it manually. You **can** however use constructor overloading, for example, if you want the option of passing in more or less optional dependencies. There's also a [Optional] attribute for ctor parameters. (then check for null)

Comment: What I meant was this :
  IProductService dSvc;
  IUnityContainer Container;
  
        public DetailsViewModel(IUnityContainer Container)
        {
            Container = container;
   FetchServices();
  }
Which based on what you recommend I will avoid using the container directly here and change it back to the approach you mentioned.